# Photoshop RGB is not accurate

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, rgb

I want to change the color to a shape, I have a serious problem, colors does NOT match with the original color (photoshop makes colors lighter):

Original color:
[image: Original color]

Photoshop color:
[image: Photoshop is not accurate]

On the other hand, the `-3` is not near from original color.

How to make Photoshop display color exactly like original color?
**EDIT:** I'm working with 32-bit color (the maximum bits for colors).

**EDIT:** 8 bit and 16 bit shows color exactly as original, but it's not the same with 32 bit (32 bit has not #Hex in color picker, 32 bit makes colors lighter)

Comment: Original color comes from Fireworks (I extracted the color from a logo). Any program (Dreamweaver, Paint, Word, PowerPoint, Excel, ...) will show color exactly like original, Photoshop is totally different, RGB is not accurate. I know RGB values (those values is in the images posted in the question)

Comment: Photoshop may be using a different color space, like sRGB, Adobe RGB, Prophoto RGB. The colors defined in one space needs to be converted to another to look right. If you are measuring the color in a browser with an eyedropper or similar tool, you may be throwing another variable into the mix. Browsers differ in their color management capabilities. If you are getting the color value from Fireworks, do you know the color space?

Comment: No, I can't get it anymore, Fireworks is no longer available in Creative Cloud downloads center (Fireworks CS6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected

Floating point color is not something you should be using unless you have floating point data sources. High Dynamic Range (HDR) images are a advanced imaging concept, right up there with the fact that human color perception is relative.

The short answer is that this will not work out for you.

The long answer is that HDR color can never be shown directly, it has to be conditioned before display. Otherwise the color values above 1.0 could not be displayed. As such the data in a HDR image is considered to be linear, anything other would make no sense. The net result is that your image is going trough a HDR conditioner AND a linear to RGB transformation (what depends on your color profile most likely sRGB*). In theory you should be able to reverse these transforms with a profile to profile change to get the color you want.**

However the conditioner is meant to be relative, just like a camera. This in turn makes the problem a bit hard to solve. But then, there is really nothing to solve, other than eliminating your mental pedantry. Your supposed to evaluate the color relation by eye NOT by numbers.

So the HDR mode is meant for data measurements and the conditioner is meant for making it look good. The integer color values shown are ONLY as a hue guide that's it.

---

* No theres no such thing as non color corrected HDR

** Doing this is certainly a good exercise, I've done it once. Unfortunately explaining how to do it would take up far too much time. Lets just say that IF you need to be this pedantic then you do not want to use 32 bit mode because it works on the concept of relative color and conditioning which is not what you operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the major difference in the HSB values in your second image compared to the first. If you click on the radio button next to the RGB this may alter the color as the saturation level between the two images you show is different.

Comment: When I use 8 or 16 bit, color is not altered, when I use 32 bit, color is different

Answer (score -1):

Don't use 32-bits colors, 32-bits in Photoshop is different:

Remember, 32-bits not:

- Makes quality better (it's the same quality as 8 and 16 bits)
- Increase colors quantity
- Improve transparency quality

The only advantage of 32-bits colors is the accuracy of gradients (gradients is more perfect than 16 or 8 bits)

Photoshop uses 32-bits different from other programs (32 bits looks the same in any program except Photoshop).

If you really need a higher quantity of bits, use 16-bits.